# Expose a listener property to control the autoStartup of all listeners on all container factories

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

The autoStartup property of a listener is currently exposed at *ContainerProperties* and also on the *KafkaListener* annotation levels.

In some cases, it may be interesting to set this property at config level for all listeners in all factories.

So, wouldn't it make sense to expose this property at *KafkaProperties#Listener* level.

Proposal: spring.kafka.listener.auto-startup

From a general point of view, it is not always clear why some *ContainerProperties* are exposed under spring.kafka.listener.* and others not. Wouldn't it make more sense to expose them all (at least the ones we can set from a property file - like syncCommits, syncCommitTimeout, deliveryAttemptHeader, pauseImmediate, etc)?

I can contribute on this feature. The idea would be to uniformize the way to set properties on a container.

Any feedback is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Auto configuration is performed by spring-boot, not individual projects like spring-kafka. You would need to submit your proposed changes there.

You can easily configure it for all listeners by injecting the factory into some other bean definition factory method:

```java
@Bean
SomeBean someBean(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory) {
    factory.setAutoStartup(false);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gary for the very quick response, I'm already using such kind of code to apply the property on all factories. @SpringBoot team, any objection to add the autoStartup property to the listener properties and also discuss the possibility of adding others missing properties (I can create a ticket and make a proposal about the missing properties)? Any feedback is more than welcome.

Comment: Github issue created on the SB project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32984